# How to burn a .mp4 to DVD+R

Tags: macos, dvd-burning

I have the osx version 10.9.2

I can't find any way to burn my .mp4 file to a DVD+R.

Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Answer (score 7):

There is a freeware software called [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html):

> Made your own movies and want to share them with family and friends? No problem. Burn can create a wide range of video discs. From VideoCD to DVD-Video discs. And DivX discs to fit more of your videos on a disc.

I use it all the time for burning mp4s to DVDs, the finished product will also work with DVD Players too.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of what you are trying to do depends on what you plan on doing with the resultant DVD. If you just want to play that file on a Mac than all you have to do is put it in a folder, right-click and select the option for burning the folder to disk (sorry, it's been a while since I did this and don't have a current Mac to reference at work for the exact procedure.)

However if you then want to play the DVD in a DVD player hooked up to a TV you may have issues with that. Look at the manual for the DVD player (or find it online) and see what disk formats it supports. Some do support movie files of various types burned to a CD or DVD (note that DVD+R is a newer format designed to avoid licensing the original [now called DVD-R] format and not all players play both kinds of discs.)

Also burning a DVD+R in the Finder will give you a Mac formatted disc that will not play on a PC and **MAY** not play on a DVD or Blu-Ray player. Check the specs on the DVD player for that as well.

If I need to burn an actual DVD (like you get movies and TV shows on commercially) I use Toast which can transcode the MP4 file into a format any standard DVD player will understand. I haven't done that in a number of years as I just play those files using Plex on a Mac Mini plugged into my TV.

Toast is a commercial product that you'll have to purchase. There may be shareware/freeware programs that do this but I don't know what they are.

Comment: All DVD and Blu-Ray players will read UDF format discs. Reading the content is another story, some newer BD players will read raw MP4 video or .mov/.avi files etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed iDVD from their suite. You will need to use a tool like iMovie (which is no longer free), or a 3rd party utility like [burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a [few](http://www.voilabits.com/resource/top-5-free-dvd-burner-mac.html) [articles](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/11-cddvd-burning-apps-for-mac/) listing 3rd-party options; the top free one seems to be [Disco](http://discoapp.com/), which was originally a commercial app.

[miDVD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/midvd/id514202850?mt=12) is available in the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

While iDVD is no longer included in Mac OS releases or in the App Store, it is still available from the [Apple Website](https://support.apple.com/downloads/idvd).

Comment: Are you sure that these upgrade versions will also work if no previous installation of iDVD is found on the Mac in question?

Answer (score 0):

UFUSoft Blu-ray Creator for Mac is reputed to be the most professional Blu-ray burning software for Mac users. The best Mac Blu-ray burning software enables you to make DVD folder/DVD disc (DVD-5/DVD-9), Blu-ray folder /Blu-ray disc (BD-25/BD-50), as well as ISO Image File out of various videos in a super easy way. To get individualized DVD and Blu-ray disc, this program allows you to design menu with customized theme, background picture, background music, button, caption and more. On top of this, the internal impressive video editing features will make it a piece of cake for you to personalize videos via options like Trim, Crop, Rotate, Effect, and Watermark. Apart from this, the powerful 2D to 3D video conversion function will enable you to obtain vivid 3D DVD/Blu-ray disc on Mac with ease.