# How to burn a dvd on 10.8

Tags: macos, dvd, mp4, dvd-burning

I have a **.mp4**-file I want to burn to a DVD to then watch on a dvd player and have automatically loop infinitely (can you program that into the dvd or is it to do with the dvd player?)

What would you reccomend I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to burn a .mp4 to DVD+R](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/how-to-burn-a-mp4-to-dvdr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html). It will convert your MP4 into a MPG and write it to the DVD as playable. (And yes, you can make the DVD loop automatically. See below.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is an old version of Burn I believe. My one looks different!